# Dataframe apply(func) returns value on one line only

Tags: python, dataframe, apply

I have this dataframe, df :

```
id       order_exist    ws_id   ws_status_code     order_id   sql_status
19          False        9          50               19-9        None
19          False        10         50               19-10       None
19          False        11         50               19-11       None
19          False        12         29               19-12       None
19          False        13         0                19-13       None
19          True         14         20               19-14       None
19          False        15         0                19-15       None
19          True         16         35               19-16       None
19          True         17         20               19-17       None
```

I have a list of tuple, tuple :

> [('19-16', 'delivered'), ('19-17', 'waiting_shipment'), ('19-14',
>   'test'), ('19-14', 'test'), ('27-1587739801134x592916474231783400',
>   'waiting_shipment')]

And I have this function :

```
def ckeck_order_status(order_id,tuple):
    for o in tuple:
        if o[0] == order_id:
            return o[1]
        else:
            return None
```

I run :

```
df['sql_status'] = df.apply(lambda x: ckeck_order_status(x['order_id'],tuple),axis=1)
```

Why do I get only the order_id "19-16" set to delivered and not the others set to their corresponding status ?

Comment: Just because `return` statement will break the function. So you'll only get the first acceptance.

Comment: can you try using yield instead of return?

Comment: If I use yield I get "<generator object ckeck_order_status at 0x7f2c..." in all sql_statuts values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function ckeck_order_status returned before completing for loop.

**Change function to**

```
def ckeck_order_status(order_id,tuple):
    for o in tuple:
        if o[0] == order_id:
            return o[1]
    return None             # only return None after exhausting for loop
```

**Output (3 matches)**

```
 id  order_exist  ...  order_id        sql_status
0  19        False  ...      19-9              None
1  19        False  ...     19-10              None
2  19        False  ...     19-11              None
3  19        False  ...     19-12              None
4  19        False  ...     19-13              None
5  19         True  ...     19-14              test
6  19        False  ...     19-15              None
7  19         True  ...     19-16         delivered
8  19         True  ...     19-17  waiting_shipment
```

Answer (score 1):

I think answer provided by @DarrylG is the correct one (I also upvoted it).

However, if you were looking for a little bit simpler solution of your problem, you can avoid [`pandas.DataFrame.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) method and you can use [`pandas.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) method. The result is the same with less code.

```
>>> df['sql_status'] = df.order_id.map(dict(tuple))
>>> print(df)
   id  order_exist  ws_id  ws_status_code order_id        sql_status
0  19        False      9              50     19-9               NaN
1  19        False     10              50    19-10               NaN
2  19        False     11              50    19-11               NaN
3  19        False     12              29    19-12               NaN
4  19        False     13               0    19-13               NaN
5  19         True     14              20    19-14              test
6  19        False     15               0    19-15               NaN
7  19         True     16              35    19-16         delivered
8  19         True     17              20    19-17  waiting_shipment
```